# Sum of Products

Tags: summation, products

What is a way to nest a product in a sum:

$$\sum_{i=2}^{N}\cos\theta_i\cos\theta_i^\prime\prod_{j=i+1}^{M}\sin\theta_j\theta_j^\prime$$

where $N$ and $M$ are two numbers?

Thank you.

Comment: Have tried, say, looking at the documentation of `Sum` or `Product`? Who knows, you might be able to find the answer there.

Comment: First, use `[i]` and not `[[i]]`, unless your thetas are pre-defined lists, second, the `Sum` in your code is not closed by an `]`. Third, what is `d`?

Comment: `NSum[Cos[\[Theta][[i]]] Cos[\[CapitalTheta]p[[i]]] Product[
   Sin[\[Theta][[j]]] Sin[\[Theta]p[[j]]], {j, i + 1, d - 1}], {i, 2, 
  d - 1}]` $\theta$ and $\theta p$ are two predefined lists of randomly generated real numbers. d is just a number, 4,5,6,7,8,...

Comment: You are probably simply confusing `\[CapitalTheta]` with `\[Theta]` or something. Everything works fine on my computer.

Comment: For something this simple, consider just using `Sum[]` instead of `NSum[]`.

Comment: I was confusing `\[CapitalTheta]` with `\[Theta]`. That's the real problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This performs the multiplications before additions in onder to avoid repetitive multiplications:

```
f[M_, n_] := Reverse[Table[Cos[θ[i]] Cos[θ'[i]], {i, 2, n}]].PadLeft[FoldList[
Sin[θ[M - #2] θ'[M - #2]] # &, Sin[θ[M] θ'[M]], Range[M - 3]], Max[n - 1, 0], 1]
```